# Matplotlib: Change contour/contourf plot levels after plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, contourf

I'm looking for a method to change the levels of a matplotlib contour/contourf plot after it has been plotted, in a way that is similar to the `Axes.set_xlim()` or `Axes.set_xticks()` methods for example. Does anything like this exist?
Thanks

```
fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Create plot with automatic levels
ax.contourf(x, y, z)

# Change levels
levels = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
ax.set_levels(levels)                 # <------ Type of method I am looking for
```

Comment: Does not exist.

Comment: There is no advantage to doing this, since the contours need to be recalculated anyway, so you may as well just delete the contour and call contourf again.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem possible. There is a `set_array` method that might seem like it would work, but testing it just now doesn't change the levels plotted. You can always call  `contourf` again.